# Android app won't open after successfully install. But it can run in emulator

Tags: android

I installed my apk file to Android TV via file explorer, but when the installation process is finished open button is disabled and the icon doesn't show.

**This is my manifest file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.admin.busstation1">

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.software.leanback"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
        android:required="false" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
        android:banner="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: In your phone where you install, have you ever install it before? Is that debug apk or release apk?

Comment: As I mentioned above I'm trying to install it on TV, I tried both debug and release apk. It's same problem when using phone

Comment: Do they have the same API Level?

Comment: Did you manage to solve the issue?